# Whats the difference between inference and conclusion?

Tags: academic-writing, article

Two questions regarding inference and conclusion.
1: Is it true that Inference can be made from any paragraph, from any line of the text but conclusion is drawn from the entire text?
2: Why often inference and conclusion look very similar?

Answer (score 2):

Inferences can be made, and often are in some fandoms, from the choice of single words. At the end of the day an inference is a guess it can be made on as much or as little data as it takes for the reader/viewer to gain the conviction that they know what's about to happen either going forward or in the end as a whole. A conclusion can only come from knowing how the story really ends and therefore must be based in complete data.

Inferences and conclusions are very similar when

A the right piece(s) of the puzzle get the reader's attention for them to infer the true shape of the final result.

B when they get the right idea from reading the wrong thing, this happens quite often, people read something, misinterpret it, and get the right answer even though their evidence says the exact opposite to what they think it does.